# How to use date-pipe inside for loop in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dictionary, date-pipe

I want to use date-pipe for the values of my dictionary. So I tried this.

```
<div *ngFor="let field of watchlist | keyvalue">
<li *ngIf="field.value  && field.key">{{field.key}}: {{field.value | date:'d MMM y'}}
```

but got an error

```
    Error: src/app/update-watchlist/update-watchlist.component.html:45:76 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(value: string | number | Date, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined):
string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(value: null | undefined, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'null'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(value: string | number | Date | null | undefined, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date | null | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

45                     <li *ngIf="field.value  && field.key">{{field.key}}: {{field.value | date:'d MMM y'}}
```

Comment: What is the type of `watchlist`?

Comment: it's a dictionary

Comment: As in a Typescript `Dictionary`? Or a `object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `field.value` is a `string` or a `number` or a `Date`. It currently is seen as `unknown`.

To do that, you'll either have to better type `watchlist` or explicitly `field.value`.